# How to change variable value in other module?

Tags: python

I have the following modules:

**test.py**

```
import test1


var1 = 'Test1'
var2 = 'Test2'

print var1
print var2

test1.modify_vars(var1, var2)

print var1
print var2
```

and the module

**test1.py**

```
def modify_vars(var1, var2):
    var1 += '_changed'
    var2 += '_changed'
```

I am expecting to get the following output:

```
Test1
Test2
Test1_changed
Test2_changed
```

I will get:

```
Test1
Test2
Test1 
Test2
```

It is mandatory to avoid importing test module in test1 module.

How to achieve this without returning values from the method ? (sort of reference passing)

Comment: *"I am expecting to get the following output"* - why? You're passing an immutable object. What's the *actual problem* you're trying to solve?

Comment: I know it is immutable, I just want to achieve this in some way and I posted what I should achieve

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Strings are immutable. You cannot do what you want. Using `+=` with a string will always return a new string, which will have nothing to do with whatever `var1` and `var2` are assigned to.

The only way to achieve something close to what you want (and, to be honest, you should probably change your requirements) is to use a list rather than separate variables, and modify its contents:

```
var = ['Test1', 'Test2']
...

def modify_var(var):
    var[0] += '_changed'
    var[1] += '_changed'
```

Comment: nice solution. I was very surprised to see that it works. Why don't you need a return?

Comment: @Glostas because this time it's modifying a mutable object (the list)

Comment: To be specific, it's modifying the *contents* of the existing list. The reference to the list itself does not need to change. If you had additional variables pointing to the individual elements in the list, they would work just like your original vars and would not see any update.

Answer (score -1):

Your function misses a return value

```
var1 = 'Test1'
var2 = 'Test2'

def modify_var(var1, var2):
    var1 += '_changed'
    var2 += '_changed'
    return (var1,var2)


(var1,var2) = modify_var(var1,var2)
print var1,var2
```

Does work.

I believe this requires minimal change to your code.

Tested with python 2.7